# Hide horizontal scrollbar but still scrollable

Tags: css

how can i hide the scroll bar from the mobile site, where still required to scroll.

```
{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this is the code i am using with div.

Please help?

[Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pdkqgw95/](http://jsfiddle.net/pdkqgw95/)

Comment: not sure what you mean. do you have a code snippet? If you set something to scroll, it will surely scroll? OR...do you want to overwrite that part of code for mobile only?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try this, may be its helpful for you.

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Comment: thanks for help. if hidden then how it will scroll ?

Comment: now impossible to scroll, but if you want that all things are comes in the given width and no need to hide horizontal scroll then check your code something is not properly positioned, or use media queries to and set width according to width of the browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
overflow-x: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

it will scroll on mobile. "overflow-x: auto;"
Check below jsfiddle for it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/pdkqgw95/3/

Comment: `overflow-x: auto` will give you a scrollbar, the OP wants to hide it.